# Can't access my wordpress site after making a change to the Functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I was editing the function.php in my site when my whole site went down. I can't even get into the dashboard or login. Any attempt to go to the site results in this message:

"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I have not gotten any email. I looked online and all the solutions say to go to the dashboard to do something but I can't access the dashboard. One solution said to use FileZilla to access the site but researching more it seems that that had to be set up in the dashboard previously to get the username to access it, something I can't do.

Is there any solutions or way to load into the site in a safe mode?

Comment: Do you host your site on shared hosting? Do you have access to anything like cpanel?

Comment: I do not know. I don't have access to anything other then the site as I'm just an employee

Comment: As I know there is no way of undoing what have happened unless you have an access to server or main hosting panel.

Comment: awesome. So I'm screwed...

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez Does your login page show up at all?  If so, does the problem happen when you are trying to login?  What error message do you get?  Is your email address the admin email address (the person who set up the site)?

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez also, did you check your SPAM folder of your email?

Comment: @finiteloop 
Any attempt to go to the site results in this message:

"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

Comment: @finiteloop I've also checked the spam folder and there is nothing there

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez were you modifying the Functions.php file from the admin panel?

Comment: @finiteloop I was modifying it from the dashboard, if thats the same as the admin panel then sure.

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez if you are a regular employee, is there someone you work with who has access to the server that the site is hosted on?

Comment: @finiteloop I have emailed them, but I was hoping for a solution so I didn't have to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228449/discussion-between-finiteloop-and-marnie-rodriguez).

Comment: Please open your wp-config file and update the WP_DEBUG to true so you can have the exact error.

Comment: I can't access anything. Where is this wp-config?